# inserir imagem em background em aplicação mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Bom Dia como deixar uma imagem de fundo na minha aplicação que está em mvc, ví alguns exemplos que fica na pasta Content mas ao abrir a página não fica rodando em background, obrigado

Comment: Você chegou a codificar alguma coisa? Pode postar?

Answer (score 1):

Opa tudo bem amigo ? No MVC geralmente utilizamos uma pasta chamada assets com subdiretórios CSS, JAVASCRIPT e IMAGENS para organizar os itens que compõem nossa VIEW, Visto que o que você quer é adicionar um Background o Ideal seria criar essa estrutura e depois adicionar dentro do seu CSS o código

```
body
{
       background-image: url('Caminho da imagem');
}
```

Segue imagem de organização de pastas em MVC

[image: Demonstração de pastas em MVC]

Comment: Muito obrigado vou alterar ainda não posso subir o projeto pq dependo do aval de todos pra postar no Git e aki tambem

Comment: Caso seja essa a resposta esperada não esqueça de confirmar a resposta para ajudar a comunidade.